# How to create an object of objects in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to create an objects which consist of other objects. I can't figure out the syntax though. I read the Little Book on CoffeeScript but it does not say what to do in this situation. I tried the following syntaxes but can't get it right:

```
  objectOfHomes = {
    {
      location: "Paris Island", age: 18
    }
  }

  objectOfHomes:
      {location: "Paris Island", age: 18},
      {location: "29 Palms", age: 18},
      {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 19},
      {location: "Iraq", age: 20},
      {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 20},
      {location: "Mesa Verda", age: 22}


  objectOfHomes =  
    {location: "Paris Island", age: 18}
    {location: "29 Palms", age: 18}
    {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 19}
    {location: "Iraq", age: 20}
    {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 20}
    {location: "Mesa Verda", age: 22}
```

Answer (score 0):

In coffeescript you could do it like this:

```
objectOfHomes:
  a:
    location: "Paris Island"
    age: 18
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely better off using an array of objects than on object of objects, unless you have a primary key of some sort which you do not appear to have.

```
 objectOfHomes = [
     {location: "Paris Island", age: 18}
     {location: "29 Palms", age: 18}
     {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 19}
     {location: "Iraq", age: 20}
     {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 20}
     {location: "Mesa Verda", age: 22}
 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include key values with your objects:

```
  objectOfHomes: 
    a: {location: "Paris Island", age: 18}
    b: {location: "29 Palms", age: 18}
    c: {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 19}
    d: {location: "Iraq", age: 20}
    e: {location: "Camp Lejeune", age: 20}
    f: {location: "Mesa Verda", age: 22}
```